# Bash Parse server_name from nginx.conf

Tags: bash, nginx, awk, sed, grep

How can I retrieve into a variable, the very first domain in the `server_name` attribute in a given nginx.conf vhost?

My vhosts are stored as files seperated out from the main nginx.conf, and while I can grep and display each one, what I am looking to do is grab just the first domain it finds and echo it (ultimately, I'll put it into a variable so I can use it elsewhere)

So... if I `grep "server_name" /each/vhost/conf` I am presented with:

```
root@getyou:/home# grep "server_name" /home/site-configs/getyou
        server_name getyou.onl;
        server_name www.getyou.onl getme.onl www.getme.onl;
root@getyou:/home# grep "server_name" /home/site-configs/kevinpirnie
        server_name kevinpirnie.com www.kevinpirnie.com;
root@getyou:/home# grep "server_name" /home/site-configs/airsweepinc
        server_name airsweepinc.com www.airsweepinc.com;
root@getyou:/home# grep "server_name" /home/site-configs/themedepot
        server_name theme-depot.net www.theme-depot.net;
```

What I am looking for given the example above would be:

```
root@getyou:/home# grep "server_name" /home/site-configs/getyou
        getyou.onl
root@getyou:/home# grep "server_name" /home/site-configs/kevinpirnie
        kevinpirnie.com
root@getyou:/home# grep "server_name" /home/site-configs/airsweepinc
        airsweepinc.com
root@getyou:/home# grep "server_name" /home/site-configs/themedepot
        theme-depot.net
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep, and Perl regexes:

```
$ grep -m1 -Poe 'server_name \K[^; ]+' getyou
getyou.onl
```

(`-m1` only take first match, `-P` Perl regexes, `-o` print only matching part. `\K` is Perl for "forget everything before this", so only the following part is printed by `-o`.)

Or, if you don't like to or can't use `grep -P`, the similar operation in Perl itself:

```
$ perl -lne 'if (/server_name ([^ ;]+)/) {print $1; exit 0}' getyou
```

Or GNU sed:

```
$ sed -ne '/server_name/{s/.*server_name //; s/[; ].*//; p; q}' getyou
```

Comment: Hope you noticed the `-P is highly experimental` warning in the GNU grep man page and so aren't actually relying on it for anything important or portable...

Comment: @EdMorton, is it known to have (had) many/serious bugs? (It's rather hard to search for `-P`) I can find references to grep's `-P` from over ten years ago, and it's rather hard to believe the PCRE library would have managed to be broken on a simple regex like that for so long.

Comment: @ilkkachu I never use it so idk but obviously the GNU grep providers (who hopefully know something about the subject!) think it's an important enough concern to characterize it as `extremely experimental` in their man page. If I was considering buying a car and the manufacturer wrote about their steering system `This is highly experimental` I wouldn't bother researching how many crashes had been caused by it, I'd just buy a different car! As you showed with your perl and sed solutions, it's not like you NEED to use `grep -P` for anything.

Answer (score 1):

`grep "server_name" a|head -1|sed 's/^\s*//g'|cut -d ' ' -f2`

Comment: hmm...  close... had to mod it a bit, becasue it was erroring on 'cut needs a delimiter' : `grep "server_name" /home/site-configs/getyou | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2`     Shows the last `;` in the line though, what can I do to dump that, and only present the domain?

Comment: got it.  thanks a ton : added to a variable, and did: `echo "${t//;}"`

Comment: Doesn't `cut -d' ' ` count every single space as a separator, so any indentation with spaces will break it (as you'd need to count the spaces to know the correct field number)?

Comment: `grep "server_name" a|head -1|sed 's/^\s*//g'|cut -d ' ' -f2|tr -d ';'`

Answer (score 0):

This will work in any awk on any UNIX system:

```
awk '$1=="server_name"{sub(/;/,""); print $2; exit}' file
```